# Mix KendoUI - MVC Server wrapper with KendoUI Core in the same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using KendoUI Core in my ASP.Net application and would like to start using KendoUI - MVC Server wrapper also.

If I buy a license for KendoUI - MVC Server wrapper, can I import its features into my current project without loosing the functionality of the KendoUI Core?

In other words: Can I use the new features of the server wrapper and those of the KendoUI Core parallel in the same project?

Best regards
Manu

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Kendo Core and Kendo MVC together. It's just like using razor and javascript on the same page. Kendo MVC is just a Razor wrapper for ease of development, it eventually boils down to the same Kendo components.